# Error in program saying "This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard"

Tags: c++

This program allows the user to enter expenses for each season and then displays the values and then the total cost at the bottom. It's giving me this error, however,

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/array:35:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
```

How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

// constant data
const int Seasons = 4;
const std::array<std::string, Seasons> Snames =
    {"Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"};

// function to modify array object
void fill(std::array<double, Seasons> * pa);
// function that uses array object without modifying it
void show(std::array<double, Seasons> da);

int main()
{
    std::array<double, Seasons> expenses;
    fill(&expenses);
    show(expenses);
    return 0;
}

void fill(std::array<double, Seasons> * pa)
{
    using namespace std;
    for (int i = 0; i < Seasons; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << Snames[i] << " expenses: ";
        cin >> (*pa)[i];
    }
}

void show(std::array<double, Seasons> da)
{
    using namespace std;
    double total = 0.0;
    cout << "\nEXPENSES\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < Seasons; i++)
    {
        cout << Snames[i] << ": $" << da[i] << endl;
        total += da[i];
    }

cout << "Total Expenses: $" << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: "This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options." Do this.

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message! You need to compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious. My question was how to change it so it will compile in c++. Hopefully that's not above your knowledge level.

Comment: @B.Wilson: Don't use `std::array`. It's C++11 only. C++11 _is_ C++ though (so you'd still be compiling "in c++" if you used the flag), and your question didn't say anything about wanting to avoid using C++11.

Comment: You might want to look at something like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), which clearly indicates features and headers that were added in later revisions of the C++ standard.